# How to show a radio button and data in same column of telerik gridview control?

Tags: wpf, telerik

[image: I am working on telerik control for WPF to show data in telerik radgridview , I need to show data in a column along with radio button so that the user can select any one of the row from the list(as shown in image)]

I have tried like this :

```
          <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  x:Name="ReferenceCols" 
                UniqueName="Reference" SortingState="Ascending" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Ref, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                     DisplayIndex="0" MaxWidth="197"
                                                     Header="title"
                                                     Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlySortableFilterableGridTextColumn}">

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <telerik:RadRadioButton Content="{Binding Reference}" CornerRadius="20" Width="30"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>

                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

but it is not working as radio button for telerik is different and it is showing content inside the button.Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik `RadRadioButton` control renders as a button and not the older style shown in your first screenshot.

In this case I would recommend using the standard WPF `RadioButton` control.